# What does curl -SL do?

Tags: linux, curl

I am looking at this command

```
curl -SL https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-10.0.0/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
```

What does "-SL" do? How would I find an answer to this using Linux command line?

Comment: Not a programming question but rather one about Linux command-line tool usage; voted to close. It could also have been answered by a simple `man curl`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [curl man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

> -S, --show-error
> -L, --location:
> (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

Next time check the docs

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` flag (short for `--location`) makes `curl` follow redirects (HTTP 3xx responses).

The `-S` flag (short for `--show-errors`) makes `curl` show the error if the request fails.